# Can't click anything in Mac OS Lion (mouse movement works, no hand cursor for clickables)

Tags: mouse, bug

I have Mac OS Lion, version 10.7, and after my screensaver activates, sometimes I can no longer click anything successfully.

I'm using a Magic Mouse with almost full battery.

These things still work:

- Moving the mouse cursor
- Right-clicking things

However, when I move the mouse cursor over something that's clickable in the browser, I don't see the hand cursor. Also when I mouse over the right-click context menu, the rows don't highlight in blue.

I can't click in to any window, menu bar, or desktop item. Switching to another virtual desktop doesn't help. When I did move to another virtual desktop, I noticed that there was a bandbox selected on the desktop that was still attached to my mouse movements, but when I right-clicked it went away and the mouse still doesn't work as described above.

The only solution right now is to logout. I haven't installed any drivers on this machine, it's a brand-new Mac Mini that came with Lion on it.

I'm running these programs:
* MacVim
* Adium
* Google Chrome
* iTunes
* iTerm latest version

These are the same applications I run on my MacBook Air with Lion installed, and I never get the same problem even with a Magic Mouse connected.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I also have a Magic Trackpad connected, and it continues to work fine. Clicking with it doesn't un-jam the mouse, though.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that disconnecting and reconnecting the mouse works.

Does anyone think the mouse is defective?

Comment: Sound like that may be the problem. I would suggesting trying the mouse on another computer and see if it exhibits the same problem.

Comment: After several months this hasn't happened again. Odd.